# What the difference between Ansible and Azure Resource Manager Template?

Tags: azure-devops, ansible, azure-resource-manager

Was wondering what the difference between Ansible and ARM Template?

Comment: Maybe you can refer to [this answer](https://dev.to/joshduffney/comment/kldo).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, `ARM` is an azure management layer whereas `Ansible` is an opensource management tool chain.

And for details, you can refer to [this link](https://dev.to/joshduffney/comment/kldo). Here is the description from that link:

> What separates Ansible from CloudFormation, Azure Resource Manager,
> and Terraform is that it's a configuration management tool. It's core
> functionality is to manage the configuration state vs deploying and
> provisioning resources. CloudFormation, Azure Resource Manager, and
> Terraform each have ways in which they can configure resources such as
> a provisioner for Terraform or using Desired State Configuration
> extensions with Azure Resource Manager templates. However, those
> technologies don't offer the same amount of functionality. Ansible is
> more comparable to Chef and Puppet in this regard.
>
> What makes Ansible a better choice is highly dependent on your
> environment and the skill sets of the teams within the organization.
> For example if you have a majority of your infrastructure on-prem and
> some in the cloud. It might make sense to stick with Ansible vs a
> cloud-platform native tool chain. I've also seen CloudFormation, Azure
> Resource Manager, or Terraform mixed with Ansible quite often. Leaving
> the deploying and provisioning of resources to these tools while using
> Ansible for the configuration. Here's a really interested article that
> might help explain why that's a common pattern.
> There are a lot of tools out there and figuring out what works best
> for your and your teams take some effort.